# Getting Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.Models.APIErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code ‘Forbidden’

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a bot running on bot framework-dispatch and leveraging NLP service from LUIS and QnA. My bot was running fine over Bot Emulator, suddenly i am getting this error -

> Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.Models.APIErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code ‘Forbidden’
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.Prediction.ResolveWithHttpMessagesAsync(String appId, String query, Nullable1 timezoneOffset, Nullable1 verbose, Nullable1 staging, Nullable1 spellCheck, String bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey, Nullable1 log, Dictionary2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.PredictionExtensions.ResolveAsync(IPrediction operations, String appId, String query, Nullable1 timezoneOffset, Nullable1 verbose, Nullable1 staging, Nullable1 spellCheck, String bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey, Nullable`1 log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.RecognizeInternalAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, LuisPredictionOptions predictionOptions, Dictionary2 telemetryProperties, Dictionary2 telemetryMetrics, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS\LuisRecognizer.cs:line 345
>
> at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.RecognizeAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS\LuisRecognizer.cs:line 145
>
> at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.DispatchBot.OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext`1 turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in F:\nikhil\Alfi\mts-qna+luis\Bots\DispatchBot.cs:line 207
>
> at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.TenantIdWorkaroundForTeamsMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotFrameworkAdapter.cs:line 995
>
> at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\MiddlewareSet.cs:line 55
>
> at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotAdapter.cs:line 167

Sometimes Luis starts responding but frequently i am getting this.

Comment: Are you using the emulator to test a locally (http://localhost) running bot or a deployed one (on Azure, etc.)? Are there any errors/messages in the emulator about Ngrok? The emulator uses Ngrok to facilitate emulated directline and has limitations.

Comment: My 1000 intents limit was over..i was using trial key..now i have resolved it by creating a resource on azure

Comment: Ah! awesome. May I suggest posting as an answer and selecting as accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sure lets c its acceptable to me or not!